# Multiple values in array

Tags: php

Is it possible to use PHP in_array to check for multiple values? For example I can do this to see if 7 is in array. What if I have 7 and 8?

```
if (in_array(7, $_SESSION[myvalues]) ) {

}
```

UPDATE:

I ran the code above. I know it works but it only looks for a single value in an array. I tried

```
if (in_array(array(7,8), $_SESSION[myvalues]) ) {...}
```

but that looks for both. I was looking for at least one. Ended up doing

```
if (in_array(7, $_SESSION[myvalues]) || in_array(8, $_SESSION[myvalues])) {...}
```

Comment: Next time you come to similar question, try to find ananswer in the manual page of array functions. It's not that hard.

Comment: ...or even try it out. It probably took you longer to ask the question than it would have done to run it.

Comment: I ran the code above. I know it works but it only looks for a single value in an array. I tried if (in_array(array(7,8), $_SESSION[myvalues]) ) {...} but that looks for both. I was looking for at least one. Ended up doing  if (in_array(7, $_SESSION[myvalues]) || in_array(8, $_SESSION[myvalues])) {}

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/array_intersect

also note that in PHP you have to put strings in quotes. so, string `myvalues` should be enclosed in quotes.